# Formik arrayhelpers.remove() method always removes the last element

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm trying to set a 'time' value to formik values.

Every time "ADD LOG" button is clicked, a new object inside the reject_log array is created.

**this initial value is passed to formik..**

```
    initialValues={{
      reject_log: [
        {
          reject_id: "",
          reject_time: "",
          reject_status: "",
        },
      ],
    }}
```

**see "RejectLogEdit".**

```
  return (
    <>
      <Formik>
        {(formikProps) => (
          <Form
            onSubmit={formikProps.handleSubmit}
            onReset={formikProps.handleReset}
          >
            <FieldArray
              name="reject_log"
              render={(arrayHelpers) => (
                <>
                  {formikProps.values.reject_log.map((rejectlog, index) => (
                    <RejectLogEdit
                      key={index}
                      index={index}
                      removeRow={(id) => {
                        arrayHelpers.remove(id);
                      }}
                      arrayHelpers={arrayHelpers}
                    />
                  ))}
                  <CustomButton
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => {
                      arrayHelpers.push({
                        reject_log: [
                          {
                            reject_id: "",
                            reject_time: "",
                            reject_status: "",
                          },
                        ],
                      });
                    }}
                  >
                    ADD LOG
                  </CustomButton>
                </>
              )}
            />
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
```

**2. This is the code inside "RejectLogEdit" component..**

```
const RejectLogEdit: React.FC = (props) => {
  const { arrayHelpers, index, removeRow } = props;
  const { form } = arrayHelpers;
  return (
    <StyledTableRow>
      <TableBodyCell>{RejectID(index, form)}</TableBodyCell>
      <TableBodyCell>{RejectTime(index, form)}</TableBodyCell>
      <TableBodyCell>{RejectStatus(index, form, removeRow)}</TableBodyCell>
    </StyledTableRow>
  );
};
```

**3. This is the code of RejectTime component that is being rendered on UI.**

```
export const RejectTime = (index: number, form: any) => {
  return (
    <FormTimePicker
      placeholder="Reject Time"
      selectSingle
      onChange={(value) => {
        form.setFieldValue(`reject_log[${index}].reject_time`, value[0]);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

**PS: Value of reject_time is getting removed from formikProps.values (as I see on console), however, not being reflected on UI. So it looks that the last item is getting removed. Am I doing something wrong in formik.setFieldValue() ?**

Comment: instead of `removeRow={(index) => { metalDetectorArrayHelpers.remove(index) }}`, try passing `metalDetectorArrayHelpers` as whole to `DetectorTestingEdit`, like `removeRow = metalDetectorArrayHelpers` then inside `RemoveDetectorTest ` component use `() => removeRow.remove(index) }`

Comment: Please add the output of the form values you're seeing in the console after calling `setFieldValue`

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

**What you are doing wrong?**

You are using index as a key,
As said in the official doc [We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). But why?? It is because [Index as a key is an anti-pattern](https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/). It may break your application and display wrong data! A very simple approach to use index as key is that,

***When you are doing crud with array,Never use index and If you are only rendering static array elements then use index as key***

So in order to correct your code, I will suggest to use reject_id as key instead of index like this

**"RejectLogEdit"**

```
return (
<>
  <Formik>
    {(formikProps) => (
      <Form
        onSubmit={formikProps.handleSubmit}
        onReset={formikProps.handleReset}
      >
        <FieldArray
          name="reject_log"
          render={(arrayHelpers) => (
            <>
              {formikProps.values.reject_log.map((rejectlog, index) => (
                <RejectLogEdit
                  key={rejectlog.reject_id}
                  index={index}
                  removeRow={(id) => {
                    arrayHelpers.remove(id);
                  }}
                  arrayHelpers={arrayHelpers}
                />
              ))}
              <CustomButton
                type="button"
                onClick={() => {
                  arrayHelpers.push({
                    reject_log: [
                      {
                        reject_id: "",
                        reject_time: "",
                        reject_status: "",
                      },
                    ],
                  });
                }}
              >
                ADD LOG
              </CustomButton>
            </>
          )}
        />
      </Form>
    )}
  </Formik>
</>
 );
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: this is also a good point. however in this particular case, that is not something that is creating an issue for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a reject_log array as an item of `reject_log` form value, `arrayHelpers.push` should be called only with the new object since it's already bounded to `reject_log` form value.

```
                      arrayHelpers.push({
                        reject_id: "",
                        reject_time: "",
                        reject_status: "",
                      });
```

Please be consistent with the naming in your code, only react components, and Typescript types should be capitalized. Also, `RejectID`, `RejectTime`, and `RejectStatus` should be written as react components because they return JSX.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that we should not use the index as a key on the div

When we remove the item from the array using the array helper this will remove the correct item, but when react is checking if we should rerender the div, the key is the same

Initial State:

```
<div key=0>
<div key=1>
<div key=2>
```

arrayHelper.remove(1)

Final State:

```
<div key=0>
<div key=1>
```

The keys are the same so react will not rerender the div and it looks like the wrong element was removed.